# How to fix "index < m_series->count()" error in xychart.cpp?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts, qdebug

I started to use [`QtCharts`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtcharts-index.html) in my application. The chart that I am considering is a *Line Chart*, using the objects [`QChart`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qchart.html) and [`QLineSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qlineseries.html). As all the points are added dynamically, I use the signal/slot system to update the chart:

```
QLineSeries* serie = new QLineSeries(this);
connect(serie, SIGNAL(pointAdded(int)), this, SLOT(onPointAdded(int)));

void MyChart::onPointAdded(int index) {
    // Delete the first items if the number of points has reached a threshold
    while (serie->points().length() >= threshold)
        serie->remove(0);
}
```

The function `onPointAdded` is called when a point is added in `serie` (a [`QLineSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qlineseries.html) object). The code snippet that I gave removes the first points in `serie` such as the number of points in the graph is always fixed (except at the beginning).

When I run this code in `Release`, there is no problem. However, when I run it on `Debug` and the number of points reaches the threshold, I obtain the following error message:

[image: Qt Debug Error Message]

This dialog box does not stop the program, but each time a point is added (and reach the threshold) a new dialog box appears on top of the previous one.

The following is the minimal code to reproduce the error:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QChart>
#include <QLineSeries>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QValueAxis>
#include <QtCharts/QChart>
#include <QtCharts/QLineSeries>

QT_CHARTS_USE_NAMESPACE

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QChart* chart = nullptr;
    QLineSeries* serie = nullptr;
    int threshold = 5;

private slots:
    void onAddPointButtonClicked();
    void onPointAdded(int index);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);

    chart = new QChart;
    serie = new QLineSeries(this);

    connect(ui->bt_addPoint, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onAddPointButtonClicked()));
    connect(serie, SIGNAL(pointAdded(int)), this, SLOT(onPointAdded(int)));

    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(serie);

    ui->graphicsView->setChart(chart);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onAddPointButtonClicked() {
    serie->append(0, 1);
}

void MainWindow::onPointAdded(int index) {
    while (serie->points().length() >= threshold)
        serie->remove(0);
}
```

I used an *UI Form* to generate the graphical interface. This interface contains a [`QChartView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html) and a [`QPushButton`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html) (to add dynamically the points).

My Qt version is **5.11.2**, and the bug has been produced using **MSVC 2017 64-bits**. The plugin **QtCharts** is needed to use the [`QChart`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qchart.html), [`QChartView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchartview.html) and [`QLineSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qlineseries.html).

I would like to know if it is possible to either fix this problem or to disable the Qt Debug Dialog Messages.

Comment: I am sorry about the code sample I gave, it was not enough to reproduce the code. I edited the post to add the simplified version of my project (I ran those files, the message box appears). I hope this update will help.

Comment: So, the mcve did help afterall to track down the problem. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

It is not a bug, but an expected result of the order in which the slots `MainWindow::onPointAdded` (in your code) and [`XYChart::handlePointAdded`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/xychart/xychart.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts7XYChart16handlePointAddedEi) are executed. Here is the whole story:

From the error message it becomes clear, that in the file `xychart.cpp` on line 142 the check of `index` against the count of `m_series` fails. The thing, which invalidates the check, is your `serie->remove(0);`. The reason is that your slot is executed **before** the slot, where the check is made, because your `connect` statement comes first. The question is: first to what? Well, this is the tricky part and I have to admit that it is indeed not immediatelly obvious. However, with some digging in the source code, one could get to the bottom of the problem. The path is the following:

- `chart = new QChart;` in your code instantiates a `QChart`, which in turn [instantiates](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/qchart.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts6QChartC1EP13QGraphicsItem6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE) a PIMPL `QChartPrivate`
- `QChartPrivate` [connects in it's constructor](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/qchart.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts13QChartPrivateC1EPNS_6QChartENS1_9ChartTypeE) `ChartDataSet::seriesAdded` to `ChartPresenter::handleSeriesAdded`:

  ```
    QObject::connect(m_dataset, SIGNAL(seriesAdded(QAbstractSeries*)), m_presenter, SLOT(handleSeriesAdded(QAbstractSeries*)));
  ```
- **IMPORTANT** Now you connect `QLineSeries::pointAdded` to `MainWindow::onPointAdded`
- `chart->addSeries(serie);` in your code causes the [`ChartPresenter::handleSeriesAdded`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/chartpresenter.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts14ChartPresenter17handleSeriesAddedEPNS_15QAbstractSeriesE) slot to be executed, where `QLineSeriesPrivate::initializeGraphics` is called:

  ```
    series->d_ptr->initializeGraphics(rootItem());
  ```
- In [`QLineSeriesPrivate::initializeGraphics`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/linechart/qlineseries.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts18QLineSeriesPrivate18initializeGraphicsEP13QGraphicsItem) a `LineChartItem` is instantiated:

  ```
    LineChartItem *line = new LineChartItem(q,parent);
  ```
- `LineChartItem` [calls](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/linechart/linechartitem.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts13LineChartItemC1EPNS_11QLineSeriesEP13QGraphicsItem) the constructor of its base class `XYChart` in the initializer list of its own constructor
- **IMPORTANT** Only now is the `connect` statement [executed](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtcharts/src/charts/xychart/xychart.cpp.html#_ZN8QtCharts7XYChartC1EPNS_9QXYSeriesEP13QGraphicsItem), which causes the troublesome for you `XYChart::handlePointAdded` slot to be called when a point is added to the series:

  ```
    QObject::connect(series, SIGNAL(pointAdded(int)), this, SLOT(handlePointAdded(int)));
  ```

Focusing only on the steps marked as important, it becomes obvious in which order do both `connect` statements come. This is also the order in which the respective slots are called.

## Solution

Having this cause in mind, I would suggest you to first add the series to the chart and **then** connect the `pointAdded` signal, i.e.:

move

```
connect(serie, SIGNAL(pointAdded(int)), this, SLOT(onPointAdded(int)));
```

anywhere **after**

```
chart->addSeries(serie);
```